# How to do a multiple folder removal in Google Drive API?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Is this now possible using Google Drive API or should I just send a multiple requests to accomplish this task?

By the way I'm using Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, you'll have to send multiple request to delete multiple files: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/delete. As you can see "delete" method receives a "fileId".

Answer (score 0):

You can batch your multiple deletes into a single HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to send multiple request just create request and add it to batch after that execute batch.

```
batch = BatchHttpRequest()

batch.add(service.files().delete(fileId=file_id), callback=callbackDummy)
batch.add(service.files().delete(fileId=file_id), callback=callbackDummy)
batch.execute(http=http)
```

to know more about it you can use [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/batch) link.